# CUPS server reporting the wrong host name

Tags: networking, server, printing, dns

I have a printer queue shared from a desktop running Mint, with the hostname of server and a local dns name of *server.home*.

I have a Ubuntu laptop which I want to connect to that shared queue. Using the GUI, I can find the queue on *server.home*, and the printer icon appears as expected in the printer list. For some reason though the printer is built with a device URI referencing *server.local*.

I can change it back to *server.home* and the printer works correctly, but the device URI for the printer queue gets changed back to *server.local* whenever I restart the laptop.

I can't find any reference to a `local` domain anywhere - I have check `/etc/hosts` on both machines, and the DNS records (name lists on the Home hub config).

Where else should i look, because I would rather not have to reset the URL name every time ..

Comment: Not sure how CUPS reverse resolve IP to name. But I expect this is related to Avahi (mDNS) which uses  `.local` domain. The global host name resolving setup is in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, If you have something like: `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4` then try changing it to:  `hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]  mdns4` so `dns` comes before `mdns`.

Comment: I don't use Avahi - I will double check if Mint has installed it for some reason.

Comment: I found `/etc/nsswitch.conf' on both server and my laptop - i have done the edits - and i will check if it made an impact on the next restart

Comment: @user.dz - if you want to make your comment into an answer - I will click it as accepted, and give you the bounty I posted. I have restarted both the server and the laptop - and reconnected to the printer queue, and the host name is being reported correctly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only service I know using `.local` domain in Linux is Avahi/Bonjour (mDNS) but not sure how CUPS reverse resolve IP to name.

1. Check the global host name resolving setup is in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
2. If you have something like:

   ```
   hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
   ```

   then change it to:

   ```
   hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
   ```

   So DNS comes before mDNS. See `man nsswitch.conf` for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much - all sorted - very much appreciated :-)